# Autoloading game function

Tags: javascript, autoload

This is basically my load function, This is the only "Load" word in my files, no vars or anything except for a button in html.

I want to make my game autoload on start, When I put load(); in my setinterval time, it keeps loading infinitely, meaning no progress. I
I was thinking a function which checks if my curren't items > load, then don't load, else load, but that would be too much coding :( and I suck at coding.

```
function load(){
var savegame = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("save"));
if (typeof savegame.Cash !== "undefined") Cash = savegame.Cash;
     if (typeof savegame.Item !== "undefined") Item = savegame.Item;
      if (typeof savegame.Item2 !== "undefined") Item2 = savegame.Item2;
       if (typeof savegame.Item3 !== "undefined") Item3 = savegame.Item3;


            document.getElementById('Cash').innerHTML = Cash;
                    document.getElementById('Item').innerHTML = Item;
                        document.getElementById('Item2').innerHTML = Item2;
                            document.getElementById('Item3').innerHTML = Item3;
};
```

Then this is my save functions. Incase it has anything to do with the load function.
Other than that it has nothing to do with anything...

```
var autosave = "on";
var autosaveCounter = 1;

function save(){
var save = {
    cash: cash,
    Item: Item,
    Item2: Item2,
    Item3: Item3,
}
localStorage.setItem("save",JSON.stringify(save));
};
```

"My" "auto save" which doesn't work very well.

```
 function toggleAutosave(){
 //Turns autosave on or off. Default on.
 if (autosave == "on"){
    autosave = "off";
    document.getElementById("toggleAutosave").innerHTML = "Enable Autosave"
 } else {
    autosave = "on";
    document.getElementById("toggleAutosave").innerHTML = "Disable Autosave"
 }
 }
```

this is what I put in my    `window.setInterval(function(){`

```
   if (autosave == "on") {
    autosaveCounter += 1;
    if (autosaveCounter >= 10){
        save('auto');
        autosaveCounter = 1;
    }
   };
```

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: setInterval is looping until you kill it with clearInterval.
I think you may need this:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: *"but that would be too much coding :( and I suck at coding"* - Is this serious? You want to code a game without too much coding?

Comment: thanks Azuarus, i'll try that.


And nnnnnn, no :P I suck at coding and I doubt I would be able to make it work. I've already tried at making a bunch of stuff and failed at it and needed to google for hours to figure out something that takes about 20 seconds to write :P

Comment: If you solved you can answer your own question. That way people know that this question was solved. Also note for coding you get better as you practice, not being able to solve a problem for hours on end that turns out to take only a couple of characters to fix is actually quite common.

Comment: Alright thanks, ill do that. And yeah, its simple stuff most of the time, still not used to it, all in due time :)

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:**

```
  //Autosave
  var saveVar;

 function autoSaveFunc() {
 saveVar = setInterval(save, 10000); //Autosave every 10 second

  }
  autoSaveFunc();


 //AutoLoad
  var loadVar;

function autoLoadFunc() {
 loadVar = setTimeout(load, 1000); //autoload

}
autoLoadFunc();
```